# How to handle an empty integer in PostgreSQL and convert it to a sting in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

I am writing a program to retrieve serial numbers for installed circuit boards for a given part number. The problem is the serial numbers are integers in postgreSQL and some of the fields are empty. My question is how do I handle those empty integers and convert them to strings? If the value is null I want to display a not install message for my label controls.
Here is my code:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select id, audio_board_serial_number,
    processor_board_serial_number, football_board_serial_number,
    thumbwheel_board_serial_number " +
    "from master_product where product_serial_number = :ProductSerialNumber;", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("ProductSerialNumber",
    clsIdStorage.ProductSerialNumber));
NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    AudioBoard = dr.GetInt32(1);
    ProcessorBoard = dr.GetInt32(2);
    FootballBoard = dr.GetInt32(3);
    ThumbwheelBoard = dr.GetInt32(4);
    if (AudioBoard == null)
        lblAudioBoardNumber.Text = "Not Installed";
    else
        lblAudioBoardNumber.Text = AudioBoard.ToString();
    if (ProcessorBoard == null)
        lblProcessorBoardNumber.Text = "Not Installed";
    else
        lblProcessorBoardNumber.Text = ProcessorBoard.ToString();
    if (FootballBoard == null)
        lblFootBallBoardNumber.Text = "Not Installed";
    else
        lblFootBallBoardNumber.Text = FootballBoard.ToString();
    if (ThumbwheelBoard == null)
        lblThumbwheelBoardNumber.Text = "Not Installed";
    else
        lblThumbwheelBoardNumber.Text = ThumbwheelBoard.ToString();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are developing for yourself, you can use whatever capitalization you like.  But when you show your code to the world, asking for help, you really should use proper, commonly accepted, standard capitalization.  The same applies to code formatting.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: You are looking for [System.DbNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare in your if-statements.

Comment: @Mike Nakis I am still a beginner, what would be a best practice to formatting? I want to learn everything I can.

Comment: well, `AudioBoard` looks like a class name, but judging by the usage, it is not.  So, it should probably begin with a lower-case letter, like `lblAudioBoardNumber`.  Or perhaps it is a property (with getter and setter,) in which case its capitalization is okay, but then you should have included its definition in the snippet to make that evident.  Anyway, never mind, it is not a very big deal.

Comment: As for the formatting, I fixed it for you. Just make sure that the indentation is proper. I also removed all the unnecessary curly brackets, not because there is a standard about them, but because I think that brevity matters here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks! I will use these practices in future programs!